# Problemas en ciclo while java

Tags: java, socket

necesito de su ayuda. Algo extraño ocurre en esta parte del código.
abc = es un objeto creado que maneja la interfaz grafica y la conexion tcp.
hasta ahí todo bien
el objeto abc crea la interfaz gráfica y maneja maneja la conexión tcp.
la interfaz tiene un botón de conexión que al pulsar crea el socket y establece la conexión con el servidor.

dentro del while esta System.out.println(); el cual no hace nada esta puesto ahí porque de no estarlo no entra en el ciclo if cuando se establece la conexión. alguien puede explicarme esto. Por que funciona de esta manera? Alguna manera de mejorarlo o solucionarlo?

```java
package gui;

/**
 *
 * @author Eliezer
 */

import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;


import network.NetworkConector;



public class BindingControlConection extends JFrame{
    
    private int numberDevice=0;
    private Boolean conected=false;
    private JPanel panelDevice[];
    private JTextArea displayOfTrama[];
    private JTextField fieldForSocket[];
    private JButton btnConnect[], btnDisconnect[];
    private JLabel lblIndicatorConection[], lblIpAddress[];
    public NetworkConector socketDevice[];
    

    public BindingControlConection(){
        
        this.setLayout(null);
        createPanelDevice(2);
        
        this.btnConnect[0].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent evt){
                Object  obj = evt.getSource();
                if (btnConnect[0] == obj){
                    connectServer(); 
                }
            }
        });
        
        this.btnDisconnect[0].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent evt){
                Object  obj = evt.getSource();
                if (btnDisconnect[0] == obj){
                    disconnectServer();
                }
            }
        });
        
        
    }
    private void connectServer(){
        
        
        String strSocket[] = fieldForSocket[0].getText().split(":");
        String ip = strSocket[0];
        int port = Integer.parseInt(strSocket[1]);
        socketDevice[0] = new NetworkConector(ip, port);
        socketDevice[0].setConection();
        System.out.println("ip: "+ip+"\nport: "+port);
        this.conected=true;
      /*  displayOfTrama[0].setText(socketDevice[0].getData());  
        System.out.println(socketDevice[0].getData());
        
    */
    }








    public static void main(String[] args){

        BindingControlConection abc =  new BindingControlConection();
        abc.setEnabled(true);
        abc.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(280,320));
        abc.setVisible(true);
        abc.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        //abc.setLayout(null);
        abc.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        abc.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        while (true){
            
            System.out.println(); // Al quitar esta linea no entra en el condicional if

            if (abc.isConnected()){
                System.out.println("eni is conected)=");
                String data = abc.socketDevice[0].getData();
                System.out.println(data);
                System.out.println("imprimiendo data");
                abc.showData(data);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Que extraño, ¿tienes el código relevante de BindingControlConection?

Comment: Cambia el System.out.println por un Thread.wait(1000), a ver si simplemente está para meter un retardo.

Comment: He agregado parte del codigo de BindingControlConection. Thread.wait no me sirve.

Answer (score 0):

No se conecta porque el campo

```
this.conected=true;
```

Se establece a true únicamente al ejecutar el método `connectServer`, este solo se llama al dar clic en el botón btnConnect, como está establecido acá

```
this.btnConnect[0].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){...}
```

Al momento de ejecutar la condición la variable estará a false y por ende no entra. Ese bloque debe estar como parte del `connectServer` o en un método separado que se invoque desde ese listener. Recomendable reorganizarlo mejor.

Comment: la verdad es que el cuando System.out.println(); esta comentada no entra al while, pero si se descomenta como esta publicado si entra al while esperando que se presione btnConnect para hacer true el this.conected y empezar a solicitar la data abc.socketDevice[0].getData() en el while(true)